# Why jQuery Plugins code is shown in source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-protection

This is just a general question about jQuery...

Suppose someone made a jQuery plugin and sells it in CodeCanyon...However he used that plugin in his website and when you go to inspect element(view source) there is the code of the plugin...

Someone can just steal it from there...  Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Can't hide from the client! :) But you can obfuscate!

Comment: ok thank you guys, i was just wondering about it :)

Comment: No which is why you should never put anything proprietary or confidential in the source of any web application. This includes comments in the html or any included javascript. obfuscation in a cute attempt to "fix" the issue but really anyone who wants your data will get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is open sourced under the MIT license, and their page [here](https://jquery.org/license/) reads

> The MIT License is simple and easy to understand and it places almost no restrictions on what you can do with a jQuery project.

Also, it is impossible to hide client-side Javascript from the user, as they can see whatever they want. However, you can attempt to obfuscate or uglify it to dissuade users from stealing it

Answer (score 0):

There is no 100%-secure way.
a) Searching for your script in the net and sueing people who didn´t pay for it
and b) Use an obfuscator to make stealing (and adapting to other sites) harder